# Syntax error in PG Admin 4 while creating a table (Postgres Version 9.4)

Tags: postgresql, primary-key, ddl

While trying to create a table from PGAdmin 4 (Postgres version 9.4). I am getting a syntax error new `data_type` of a column name. This error occurs for any datatype. Below is the Query that I am running.

```
CREATE TABLE films (
    code        char(5) CONSTRAINT firstkey PRIMARY KEY,
    title       varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    did         integer NOT NULL,
    date_prod   date,
    kind        varchar(10),
    len         interval hour to minute
);
```

Below is the error that I am getting.

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "char"
LINE 2:     code        char(5) CONSTRAINT firstkey PRIMARY KEY,
                        ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 141
```

I am getting this error for all the queries that I ran for creating a table for all the data types. This query is picked straight out of the postgresql documentation - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/sql-createtable.html

Therefore, it must be some PGAdmin configuration that is wrong at my end.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe some hidden strange characters. Try pasting the code into a plain text editor, copy it from there, then try to run it again. And [don't use the `char` data type](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_char.28n.29)

Comment: I copy & pasted the statement from above and it executed no problem on pgAdmin4 with a postgres 10.8 backend.

Comment: Okay. Let me try with postgres 10.8. I have been getting this error even if I write the simple create table query without copy pasting it.

Comment: I didn't count, but I don't believe that the indicated error position is at character 141 of the query you posted. Perhaps the preceeding SQL statement is missing a terminating `;`?